# Insert rows through a loop with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this query :

```
SELECT kailiv, count(*) as PALETTES from FGE50NEUV1.gesupe 
where etasup='30' and cumcol>0 and kailiv>=1 
and kailiv<=66 
group by kailiv 
order by kailiv
```

This returns things like :

```
[
  { KAILIV: 1, PALETTES: 15 },
  { KAILIV: 2, PALETTES: 7 },
  { KAILIV: 3, PALETTES: 2 },
  { KAILIV: 6, PALETTES: 4 },
  { KAILIV: 7, PALETTES: 1 },
  { KAILIV: 13, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 15, PALETTES: 3 },
  { KAILIV: 20, PALETTES: 8 },
  { KAILIV: 26, PALETTES: 2 },
  { KAILIV: 27, PALETTES: 1 },
  { KAILIV: 29, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 30, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 31, PALETTES: 4 },
  { KAILIV: 32, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 62, PALETTES: 7 },
  { KAILIV: 63, PALETTES: 6 },
  { KAILIV: 64, PALETTES: 4 }
]
```

And I would like to have a row for **each "kailiv" between 1 and 66, with a 0 if it's empty**

Is it easier to make it after fetching the data through JS, or directly in SQL, and how can I do this ?

EDIT :
When I try this after the query :

```
for(let i=1; i<=66; i++) {
    let quai = travees[i].KAILIV
    if (quai != i) {
        travees.slice(i-1,0,{KAILIV : i, PALETTES: 0})
    }
}
```

I've got an error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'KAILIV')

Comment: It's easier to do it in a regular programming language  like JS than SQL.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQLite, SQL-Server?

Comment: Do you have a row in FGE50NEUV1.gesupe for each KAILIV and it's just being filtered out by etasup='30' and cumcol>0, or are there KAILIVs between 1 and 66 that have no rows in the table?
If there are rows, then you could do something like:
SELECT kailiv, SUM(CASE WHEN etasup='30' and cumcol>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PALETTES and remove the etasup='30' and cumcol>0 from your where clause.
If there are no rows - then it's definitely easier in JS.

Comment: Hi everyone.
Barmar, I'm using IBM DB2. Thanks Bruce I'll give it a try. If it's easier with JS how can I do ?

Comment: Just tested it. It seems like I don't have a row for each "kailiv"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to do in javascript, the general idea is turn your array into a lookup keyed on `KAILIV` and then just loop from 1 to 66 pulling either the value or 0

```js
const input = [
  { KAILIV: 1, PALETTES: 15 },
  { KAILIV: 2, PALETTES: 7 },
  { KAILIV: 3, PALETTES: 2 },
  { KAILIV: 6, PALETTES: 4 },
  { KAILIV: 7, PALETTES: 1 },
  { KAILIV: 13, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 15, PALETTES: 3 },
  { KAILIV: 20, PALETTES: 8 },
  { KAILIV: 26, PALETTES: 2 },
  { KAILIV: 27, PALETTES: 1 },
  { KAILIV: 29, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 30, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 31, PALETTES: 4 },
  { KAILIV: 32, PALETTES: 10 },
  { KAILIV: 62, PALETTES: 7 },
  { KAILIV: 63, PALETTES: 6 },
  { KAILIV: 64, PALETTES: 4 }
]

// make a map of the data
const indexed = Object.fromEntries(input.map(x => [x.KAILIV,x.PALETTES]));

// function to generate a range of numbers (1-66 in our case)
function range(size, startAt = 0) {
    return [...Array(size).keys()].map(i => i + startAt);
}

// generate a new set of data
const newData = range(66,1).map(k=> ({
    KAILIV:k,
    PALETTES: indexed[k] ?? 0
}))

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Hey, I don't understand all the code so I've to work on it, but it works perfectly. Thanks a lot ;)